# Angularjs http.get get http with provided username and password

Tags: angularjs

The site I am connecting to requires username and password. How I can implement this?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"/>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"></div>

<script>
    var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('customersCtrl',function($scope,$http){
        $http.get("http://xxx").success(function (response) {
            $scope.names = response.records;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How does it require username? Most API's that use username and password for some form of login are a POST with the username and password int he body. If its a GET is it part of the url or as a query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to pass your username and password through with your URL, so for example :

```
<script>
    var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('customersCtrl',function($scope,$http){
        $http.get("http://www.myWebPage/USERNAME:PASSWORD@blahblah.com").success(function (response) {
            $scope.names = response.records;
        });
    });
</script>
```